# Issue in insert query mysql error#1364

Tags: mysql

my query is

```
INSERT INTO `session_card` (`flags`, `history`, `showtime`, `session_id`, `card_id`, `card_mode`) VALUES ('', 'ö', '12', 9410, '256', 'rw')
```

and the table structure is

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `session_card`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `session_card` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `session_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_id` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `history` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `flags` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `showtime` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_mode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `session_card_unique_key` (`session_id`,`card_id`,`card_mode`),
  KEY `fk` (`session_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

COMMIT;

Now I dont understand what is the issue here also my phpmyadmin show only error code it doesnt give me the error expatiation. Any one can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `AUTO_INCREMENT` on your `id` column, or you will need to pass a unique id manually every time you insert a row.

Change:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `session_card` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

to:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `session_card` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

I would also suggest adding `UNSIGNED` as well since id's usually don't contain negative values.

Comment: phpmyadmin show only error code it doesnt give me the error expatiation. Could you please help me with that

Comment: @MohdMobeen - You can always use Google to find what the error code means. I don't use PHPMyAdmin so I can't help you with that part.

Answer (score 0):

In your schema, you have given **id` int(11) NOT NULL** but while inserting data you are not passing any value for id. as id is a not null constraint you should pass the value for id.

Answer (score 0):

Modify you ID column to `AUTO_INCREMENT` flag

```
ALTER TABLE session_card MODIFY id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Make sure you table is empty before executing the above sql

Answer (score 0):

If you are not setting a primary key id to Auto Increment then provide a value while inserting.
Otherwise, set it to AutoIncrement. This is better way to assigning a value.

```
INSERT INTO `session_card` 
(`id`,`flags`, `history`, `showtime`, `session_id`, `card_id`, `card_mode`) VALUES 
('1','', 'ö', '12', 9410, '256', 'rw')
```

Comment: If you are using this table, then for inserting you are calling a method for insertion, then in that method make a counter which takes the last value from this table of id and increament it with 1 or any value which you are using it...then assign that value to the id column and other value as you are inserting in it

Comment: So basically you're advocating for handling the auto increment manually (which includes extra database calls) instead of letting the database do it for you? If you have 2 rows with id 1 and 2. You delete the row with id 2. Next time you insert a new row, that row would get id 2 as well. Any references (old links etc) that contains that id will now show the wrong record.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson By making function and trigger which can take the last value of id which is highest and increament it by 1 or any other value then insert it

Comment: That wouldn't solve the issue I just mentioned and I still don't get the reasoning behind doing that manually? There's absolutely no reason for it. Just add AUTO_INCREMENT on that column and let the database take care of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Might be it's because of strick mode

Disable it:

```
 SET sql_mode = '';
```

After this try insert query.

Answer (score 0):

please make id key is auto increment
like following.

ALTER TABLE session_card MODIFY id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

Otherwise add manually id at insertion time. like following.

INSERT INTO `session_card` 
(`id`,`flags`, `history`, `showtime`, `session_id`, `card_id`, `card_mode`) VALUES 
('1','', 'ö', '12', 9410, '256', 'rw')